# How listen for changes to scrollTop on a DIV by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I've prevented scrolling n my DIV by using `event.preventDefault()` on the `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` events but that only works for scrolling initiated via the mouse/wheel.

I've discovered a weird situation where if someone presses the tab button a number of times after clicking in an input box, it can force a scroll to another input in a different form. That changes the `scrollTop` value. I want to prevent this. How would I stop this?

Edit: The DIV has `overflow: hidden;` but the browser still scrolls it.

Comment: @Itay maybe not as the overflow is hidden which seems to be different.

Comment: You are right. What about using `tabindex`?

Comment: @Itay I am doing that along with onblur but it seems: 1. a bit messy, 2. there might be another keypress or other event that could cause unwanted scrolling. (I don't understand why an `overflow: hidden` div is scrollable at all)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Overflow just defines whether overflowing content is shown or not. I'm usually solving this kind of issues with `tabindex`.

Comment: Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/MTmwT/) fiddle. I think that's what you want

Comment: disable input in the bit which scrolls, and re-enable it after you're done. It can be done with fairly simple JavaScript, especially if you use a library like jQuery.